# random slideshow with two images with transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random, transition

I am stuck with a javascript two images 'slideshow' with random appearance of images at random intervals.
So far it works, but now I want to add transitions when showing and hiding the images. I am wondering if it is possible to show randomly only one picture.

I have this code so far:

```
var j;
var rand = 700;
function randomize() {
    loadRandom();
    rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(5000-700+1))+700; 
    clearInterval(j);
    j = setInterval('randomize();', rand);
}
j = setInterval('randomize();', rand);



function loadRandom(){
    var ranNums=[];
    while(ranNums.length<7){
        var t=Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
        if(ranNums.indexOf(t)==-1)
            ranNums.push(t);
    }
    var i=0;
    $('#imageTable > .image-container > img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','images/image-'+ranNums[i]+'.jpg');
        i++;
    });
}
```

Here it is online: http://www.steef.111mb.de

I hope someone can help me,
Cheers.

Edit: 
I added *fadeIn* but still need to figure out how to use the *fadeOut*.
To only show only one picture I use a higher number at Math.random() as I have pictures an hide the missing image icon.
I know it is no clean code, but can not figure out how to do it better.
I am wondering now if it is possible to disable *fadeIn/fadeOut* when the same image is showing twice in a row.

```
var j;
var rand = 900;
function randomize() {
    loadRandom();
    rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(7000-900+1))+900; 
    clearInterval(j);
    j = setInterval('randomize();', rand);
}
j = setInterval('randomize();', rand);

function loadRandom(){
    var ranNums=[];
    while(ranNums.length<7){
        var t=Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
        if(ranNums.indexOf(t)==-1)
            ranNums.push(t);
    }
    var i=0;
    $('#imageTable > .image-container > img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','images/image-'+ranNums[i]+'.jpg');
        i++;
    });
    $("img").hide();
    $("img").fadeIn(500);
    $("img").error(function(){
            $(this).hide();
    }); 
};
```

http://steef.111mb.de//index2.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with something like this

```
$("img").hide();
    $('#imageTable > .image-container > img').each(function(){
          if(ranNums[i]<=7)
           {$(this).attr('src','images/image-'+ranNums[i]+'.jpg');
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
           }

        i++;
    });
```

And now your problem is how to prevent situation when both are out of bounds. But that wasnt't in scope of question

Comment: Thank you, that looks cleaner indeed

Comment: @Stefan as i see you are new here -  custom is that when you find some answer useful give upvote, if some answer solves your problem completely, mark as solved (pick best answer). And if you google some problem and find solution on  stackoverflow, also upvote answer  that solves your problem. Welcome in community  and happy codding.